# I am getting the errors when i am running the command the qtl seq downloaded by conda. I am running following command

Tags: python-3.x

```
[QTL-seq:2019-10-09 09:13:37] !!ERROR!! bcftools concat -a -O z -o Chikpea_qtl/30_vcf/qtlseq.vcf.gz Chikpea_qtl/30_vcf/qtlseq.*.vcf.gz >> Chikpea_qtl/log/bcftools.log 2>&1
Failed to open Chikpea_qtl/30_vcf/qtlseq.NW_004516646.1.vcf.gz: could not load index
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/jthakur/Desktop/Software/QTL-seq/qtlseq/mpileup.py", line 191, in concat
```

check=True)

```
File "/home/jthakur/anaconda2/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
```

output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'bcftools concat -a -O z -o Chikpea_qtl/30_vcf/qtlseq.vcf.gz Chikpea_qtl/30_vcf/qtlseq.*.vcf.gz >> Chikpea_qtl/log/bcftools.log 2>&1' returned non-zero exit status 255.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/home/jthakur/anaconda2/bin/qtlseq", line 11, in
load_entry_point('qtlseq', 'console_scripts', 'qtlseq')()

```
File "/home/jthakur/Desktop/Software/QTL-seq/qtlseq/qtlseq.py", line 192, in main
```

QTLseq(args).run()

```
File "/home/jthakur/Desktop/Software/QTL-seq/qtlseq/qtlseq.py", line 123, in mpileup
```

mp.run()

```
File "/home/jthakur/Desktop/Software/QTL-seq/qtlseq/mpileup.py", line 232, in run
```

self.concat()

```
File "/home/jthakur/Desktop/Software/QTL-seq/qtlseq/mpileup.py", line 194, in concat
```

sys.exit()

```
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```